# Specify command line options to execute in Cabal file?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, cabal

I have a Haskell test program in a Cabal sandbox. I'd like to be able to do `cabal run` and have it provide command line arguments automatically when running the program. Can I specify these arguments in the `proj.cabal` file?

I see `--prog-options` as an option to `cabal` but no configuration file options, it seems?

Comment: Have you tried using cabal flags to conditionally include a separate module based on the flag? I'm not sure if this works with `cabal run`